# How to zoom in and zoom out mutiple images on scroll view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

i have a scroll view with multiple images and i am using this code. i have the images with dimensions (2121 x 2892) in Portrait and (2112 x 1500) in landscape mode

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;

NSInteger numberOfViews = [arrayImages count];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin  +30, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-60 , self.view.frame.size.height)];

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

i want to implement the zoomin and zoom out functionality on double tab and moving with two fingers. I saw many sample application but i am not be able to do the same. if anybody have its own code please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to implement the zoomin and zoom out functionality on double tab and moving with two fingers.

For the zoom in on double tap, check out the gesture recogniser part of [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).

As for moving around with 2 fingers, you could use a `UIPanGestureRecogniser` for 2 touches and change the `contentOffset` of the scroll view accordingly when a pan is recognised.

Comment: Yes i use the same UIPanGestureRecogniser and the images gets zoomin but i have mutiple images on the UIScrollView, and scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
when i scroll the images after zooimg the application crash.

Comment: The crash will remove but when we rotate the device after zooming the image will not appear accurately.Its size becomes change.

Answer (score 0):

simple add a subview to scrollview and add all imageViews in it. and in scrollview's delegate method and do like this

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
  return view;
}
```